What do Strunk and White discuss in The Elements of Style concerning the terms "to-day," "every one," and other compound words?
What is this section of The Elements of Style discussing?

Write to-day, to-night, to-morrow (but not together) with hyphen.
Write any one, every one, some one, some time (except the sense of formerly) as
two words.

Are the terms anyone, everyone, someone, sometime, today, tonight, and tomorrow incorrect?
Feel free to correct title! I was uncertain how to best display my concern in a coherent fashion.

That’s in the chapter titled VI. WORDS OFTEN MISSPELLED; I presume those are examples of misspellings. “[A common mistake is to] write some one as two words.”

The date of the version of S & W quoted needs to be given. Hyphenation / solidification of compounds follows reasonably predictable trends.

This question is similar to: is there a rule to determine whether a word is a closed compound word. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // The date of the version of S & W quoted needs to be given. Hyphenation / solidification of compounds (the transformations) follow reasonably predictable trends.

Although the PDF version of The Elements of Style cited in the posted question above is presented (by someone at faculty.washington.edu) as being an edition—albeit an undated one—co-authored by William Strunk and E.B. White, it seems to be a reset version the original edition of the book written solely by Strunk and published in 1918. I don't see any differences in content (as opposed to typeface) between it and the 1918 edition that is viewable in full through Google Books, anyway. This makes sense, as there would be copyright issues with posting a fully viewable edition of the book that included White's changes from 1959 or later.
The original (1918) edition of William Strunk, The Elements of Style includes the wording cited in the question above at the end of the final page of the book, in a section titled "Words Often Misspelled":

Write to-day, to-night, to-morrow (but not together) with hyphen.
Write any one, every one, some one, some time (except the sense of formerly) as two words.

I suspect that E.B. White removed this antiquated orthographical advice from the edition of the style guide that he revised and published in 1959 after he "reexamined [the original Strunk edition] in 1957." At any rate, the entire Strunk section on spelling was long gone by the 1971 edition (which happens to be searchable in snippet window view at Google Books).
We can track the fortunes of Strunk's attempt to hold the line on what he considered the correct spelling of the seven hyphenated or open words he specifies in his 1918 style guide by looking at how successive editions of Webster's Collegiate Dictionary spelled them. Here are the spellings that appear at the heads of the relevant entries in the first edition (1898) of that dictionary:

To-day, To-night, To-morrow, Together, Anyone [with the parenthetical note "Commonly written as two words"], Everyone [with the parenthetical note "Commonly separated, every one"], Sometime

Curiously, this edition of Webster's Collegiate Dictionary omits any entry for "someone/some one."
The third edition (1916) and the fourth edition (1931) break with the first edition only in replacing the entry for "Everyone" with an entry for "every one or everyone"—a slight step backward, it might seem, except that the accompanying definition asserts that for the meaning "everybody," the term is "in this sense preferably written everyone." There is still no entry for "someone" or "some one."
But in the fifth edition (1936), the dam bursts. Here are the spellings prescribed in that edition:

today [or] to-day, tonight ["Also to-night"], tomorrow ["Also to-morrow"], anyone [no parenthetical note], everyone [with no parenthetical note, but accompanied by a separate entry (to cover usage of the term followed by "of")] every one, someone [finally], sometime

The sixth edition (1949) retains all of the fifth edition's wording—but the seventh edition (1963) brings Webster's fully intro the modern world:

today, tonight, tomorrow, anyone, everyone, someone, sometime

The seventh edition includes no parenthetical notes, no double entries, and no alternative spellings for any of these terms. All of Strunk's spelling preferences (except together and sometime in the specific sense of "formerly"—which were his concessions to modernity back in 1918) are officially dead, according to Merriam-Webster.
The  evolving spelling recommendations in the Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series indicate that Strunk's preference for to-day, to-night, and to-morrow was thoroughly mainstream when he wrote The Elements of Style, and these remained the dominant forms for most of the next two decades. During the period from 1936 to 1962, their status was reduced to that of a still-acceptable variant; but in 1963, they ceased to be recognized as contemporaneous spellings at all.
Strunk's preferences for any one, every one, some one, and some time were already edging toward obsolescence in 1918; and by 1936, Merriam-Webster no longer acknowledged those spellings.

Many words such as to-day were spelled with hyphens until fairly recently.
See the following post for more information: Change from to-day to today
Strunk and White appear to be referencing a phenomenon that would later become the more standardized spelling.
